# Python decorator error handling

Tags: python, plugins, decorator, bottle

I am creating bottle rest API and I want to use function decorator at some endpoints to authentificate user. Decorator code is:

```
def authenticating_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        try:
            '''
            auth user before execution of the required code
            if user is not authenticated bottle.HTTPError is raised
            '''
            auth()  
            return func
        except HTTPError as e:
            return handle_auth_error  

    return wrapper()

return authenticating_decorator
```

Handle auth error function:

```
def handle_auth_error(error):
    return {
        "code": error.status_code,
        "name": error.body.get('name'),
        "description": error.body.get('description')
    }
```

Everything is working fine except that I have bottle plugin installed to catch exceptions and convert them to required JSON and API response has content typeapplication/json

When exception occurs in **auth** method, API return error in known html format because it somehow skips my error plugin. (I mahbe do not fully understand application flow when using both plugins and decorators)

Call method of my error plugin:

```
def __call__(self, callback):
    def wrapper(*a, **kw):
        try:
            rv = callback(*a, **kw)
            return rv
        except HTTPError as e:
            response.status = e.status_code
            return {
                "code": e.status_code,
                "name": e.body.get('name'),
                "description": e.body.get('description')
            }
    return wrapper
```

My point is that I have to pass function to the plugin because of line **rv = callback(*a, **kw)**

and since I have multiple types of exception in auth() method in decorator I want to pass exception as argument to `handle_auth_error` in decorator

But if I type `return handle_auth_error(e)` the function returns dict, not the function and I am getting exception dict object is not callable at code line `rv = callback(*a, **kw)`

How can I return function with argument from decorator withouth calling it in decorator but calling it in plugin?
Or how can I pass exception as parameter to plugin?

The possible solution is creating own function to handle for every possible exception with 'switch' statement based on exception name, but I want to do it more programically:

```
 return {
     'HEADER_MISSING': handle_header_missing_exception,
     'TOKEN_EXPIRED': handle_expired_token_exception,
      etc ... : etc...
            }.get(e.body.get('name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your decorator is not written correctly, shouldn't it be:

```
def authenticating_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        try:
             '''
            auth user before execution of the required code
            if user is not authenticated bottle.HTTPError is raised
            '''
            auth()  
            return func(*args, **kw) #calling func here
        except HTTPError as e:
            return handle_auth_error(e)  #calling the handle_auto_error here

return wrapper #notice - no call here, just return the wrapper
```